# Espresso activity stack

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm just start to writing tests on Espresso and I've been faced with a problem:

How can I pre-start activity when testing some another activity. For example I want to check if my activity finished when I pressed some button and the previous activity in stack is shown now. How can I check that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `intented`. Take a look at googles documentation for intents [here](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/) and the sample code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IntentsBasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/DialerActivityTest.java#L113)